# limits to \oplus not working and double ended arrow equation

Tags: math-mode, arrows, math-operators

I am having an equation which having `\oplus` with limits, but `\limits` for `\oplus` gives error and there is another critical equation with double ended arrow. can anyone please help me to key this equation.
[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: people spend their day writing that comment but even google understands what the OP asks for (since it directed me to that page)!! \documentclass is NO NEED!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a larger `\bigoplus` that acts as operator. Or `\oplus` can be wrapped in `\mathop`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\bigoplus_{\substack{\rho\in g,\\\rho \neq \rho_0}}\]       
\[\mathop{\oplus}_{\substack{\rho\in g,\\\rho \neq \rho_0}}\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

This is a job for a graphic tool, for example `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2pt]
{} & \mathrm{VI} \arrow{r} & \mathrm{X} \\
{} \\
\smash[b]{\bigoplus\limits_{\substack{\rho\in\mathfrak{g}\hat{\,}\\\rho\ne\rho_{0}}}}
\vphantom{\bigoplus} \mathrm{V}
  \arrow{uur} \arrow{ddr} \\
{} & & \mathrm{VIII} \arrow{uuu} \\
{} & \mathrm{VII} \arrow{ur} \arrow{dr} \\
{} & & \mathrm{IX}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

The subscripts are smashed out, because otherwise they would make an arrow start too low. Notice `\substack` for the two row subscript.

[image]

You can make the diagram even more compact with `row sep=-4pt`

[image]

As suggested by Qrrbrbirlbel, the `\smash` trick can be avoided:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-4pt]
{} & \mathrm{VI} \arrow{r} & \mathrm{X} \\
{} \\
|[text depth=+0pt]|\bigoplus\limits_{\substack{\rho\in\mathfrak{g}\hat{\,}\\\rho\ne\rho_{0}}}
\mathrm{V}
  \arrow{uur} \arrow{ddr} \\
{} & & \mathrm{VIII} \arrow{uuu} \\
{} & \mathrm{VII} \arrow{ur} \arrow{dr} \\
{} & & \mathrm{IX}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Without `\smash` and `\vphantom` (ignoring all possible depths): `|[text depth=+0pt]| \bigoplus\limits_{…} \mathrm{V} <arrows>`

Comment: hi for this code im getting output like lengthy arrows which exceeds page corners . im not getting the same displayed output

Comment: @ravi Maybe you have an outdated version of `tikz-cd`

Comment: im using miktex for files . dont know how to update tikz-cd